# Отправка данных

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

Надо отправить данные типа int на front-end `await Clients.All.SendCoreAsync("Up", Y_Bot--);`, но это не удаётся сделать т.к. int не ссылочный тип данных. Как отправить данные типа int?

Вот блок кода :

```
public async Task Up(int y_bot)
    {
        if (BlockCoord.IsBlockY(y_bot - 1) == false)
        {
            Y_Bot = y_bot
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("Up", Y_Bot--); // ??
        }
        else
        {
            Y_Bot = y_bot;
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("Up", Y_Bot ); // ??
        }
    }
```

Comment: Преврати в строку

Comment: Отдайте строку, а фронтенду скажите что это число (лучше использовать что-то на подобии `tryParse()` ну или сделать свою обработку

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task Up(int y_bot)
{
    if (BlockCoord.IsBlockY(y_bot - 1) == false)
    {
        Y_Bot = y_bot
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("Up", (Y_Bot--).ToString()); // ??
    }
    else
    {
        Y_Bot = y_bot;
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("Up", Y_Bot.ToString()); // ??
    }
}
```

а потом на клиенте принимаете `string` и говорите что это `int`